# http get request using Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a question about a get and put request using angular.
I know how I can do a get or put request when I for example click on a button. For that, I just have to bind my request to the button. But now I want to be able to make a get request for example without some button. that means ich enters for example a barcode and just clicks on my keyboard on entering and releases my get request.
A normal code for a get look for example like:

```
this.codeService.getBarcode(barcode).subscribe(_=>
  ...
)
```

my question is what do I have to do in the subscribe to be able to do this get request if I don't have some button to click

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `get` data when you load the app without clicking but in `OnInit` time.
You can write direct in your component but that is not a clean code.
You better write a service which will hold `get` and `put`.
Here is a little example.
Here you have `get`, `post`, `put` and `delete`

```
export class EmployeeService {

  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8081/rest/user";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployee(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }
  createEmployee(employee: object): Observable<object> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, employee);
  }


  updateEmployee(id: number, value: any): Observable<object> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, value);
  }

  deleteEmployee(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  getEmployeesList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
}
```

You need then to add `HttpClientModule` in the `app.module.ts`

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule <-- This here
  ],
```

You can have an interface like this.

```
export class Employee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

Your component `ts`

```
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  employees: Observable<Employee[]>;

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData();
  }

  reloadData() {
    this.employees = this.employeeService.getEmployeesList();
  }

  deleteEmployee(id: number) {
    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id)
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data, id));
    this.reloadData();
  }

  employeeDetails(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['details', id]);
  }
}
```

Your component `HTML`

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h2>Employee List</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Extra</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees | async">
          <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
          <td><button (click)="deleteEmployee(employee.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
              <button (click)="employeeDetails(employee.id)" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 10px">Details</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @HermanNguekeng No problem.
But I am not really understanding what do you want.
Do you want to make a get request when you for example enter a barcode and through this barcode you get the data ?

Comment: there im writing my question again :-) with  more details

Comment: you can see that top of your first answer

Comment: @HermanNguekeng Then you need to use `keyup enter` or something like that in your `input`.
`<input type="number" (keyup)="sendUser()" class="form-control" id="obarcode" name="obarcode" required>`